# problems with pairwise blast in biopython

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, blast

I try to run a pairwise blast between two sequences within a python script and using the biopython blast tools.

I have no problems running a blast against a local database by adding parameter `db='blast_database'` to blast_cline. But if I replace this parameter by `subject='tmp_subject.fas'` it does not work.

My code:

```
from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbiblastnCommandline

blast_cline = NcbiblastnCommandline(query='tmp_query.fas', subject='tmp_subject.fas', evalue=1, outfmt=5, out='tmp.xml')

blast_cline()
```

I receive this error message:

```
Bio.Application.ApplicationError: Non-zero return code 3 from 'blastn -out tmp.xml -outfmt 5 -query tmp_query.fas -evalue 1 -subject tmp_subject.fas', message 'BLAST engine error: Empty CBlastQueryVector'
```

Comment: Not sure if it is applicable to your case, but [here](https://github.com/bawee/bwast) I read "Genbank files output by Artemis can sometimes cause [`BLAST engine error: Empty CBlastQueryVector`] due to the absence of a valid header."

Comment: Thank you for this hint! But if run the command <blastn -out tmp.xml -outfmt 5 -query tmp_query.fas -evalue 1 -subject tmp_subject.fas> on the shell it works fine. Thus, I guess there is some problem with the implementation in biopython...

Comment: from the command-line, show the outputs of `blastn -version` VS. `python -c 'from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbiblastnCommandline; print(NcbiblastnCommandline(version=1)())'`

Comment: @Chris_Rands this should probably migrated no? It is solvable here, but would be more easily addressed on [bioinformatics](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbiblastnCommandline
blast_cline = NcbiblastnCommandline(query='tmp_query.fas', subject='tmp_subject.fas', evalue=1, outfmt=5)()[0]
print(blast_cline)
```